Incorrect Counterexample for $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e., $\sup_n ||f_n||_p < \infty \implies \int f_ng \rightarrow \int fg$
This question has been asked before: Let $1 < p < \infty, f_k \in L_p(E), k = 1, 2, ..., $ and $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}f_k(x) = f(x)$ a.e., $\sup_{1 \leq k<\infty}||f_k||_p \leq M$.  Show that for any $g \in L_{p'}(E)$, where $p'$ is the conjugate of $p$, $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\int_Ef_k(x)g(x)dx = \int_Ef(x)g(x)dx$
I know it's true, which is why I'm confused where the following `counterexample' goes wrong:

For $X = [0,1]$, let the sequence $f_n := n^{1/p}1_{[0,1/n]}$. Then, $||f_n||_p = \int_0^{1/n} n = 1$, i.e., we have uniformly bounded $L_p$ norm.
However, note that $f_n \rightarrow f = 0$ a.e., and $\int f = 0$ of course.
But since $g \equiv 1 \in L^q([0,1])$, we have a contradiction: $\int_0^1 f_n g = \int_0^1 f_n = 1$, whereas $\int_0^1 fg = 0$, i.e., we don't have weak convergence.

Where am I going wrong?
